# ReactJs: Handle input text with many paragraphs

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react,

I want to make the user type some texts (may contain over 1 paragraph) in the input box, then display it.

If I use `<input type="text">` tag, the user can not press enter to type another line.

If I use `<span role="textbox" contentEditable={true}>` tag, although the user can type

```
para1.
para2.
```

then I save the text and display them by putting the input in the `<p>` tag, the paragraphs are concatenated:

```
para1.para2.
```

How can I allow users to type paragraphs and display them normally?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: you can *try* to use `<pre>` which should preserve formatting, but it's more likely that you will want to convert your content into HTML markup before displaying it.

Comment: Are you just talking about a `<textarea />`?

Answer (score 1):

Your best option for the input would be a simple  that allows writing multiple paragraphs. As for displaying text, you could use something similar to this:

```
<p>
  {text.split('\n').map((item, key) => (
    <Fragment key={key}>
      {item}
      <br />
    </Fragment>
 ))}
</p>
```